# Navigation bar obscures headings

Tags: html, css

I am creating a resume site, and I ran into a problem that the navigation bar blocks the title, that is, it looks like this https://prnt.sc/ggkfkwSV8KUp, and I need so https://prnt.sc/oX0Hw2G_d_xk.

I tried to indent, but the navbar follows this title and obscures it all the time, no matter how indented I am, how can I fix this? I added code here, (yes, the styles here are not very, not adapted, I know) I removed a lot of code, left only two sections to show, but the fact is that it doesn’t work like mine, more precisely in a small form works like mine, but if you expand it to the whole page, then the navbar does not block the title, but it fits a little, but it can still be shown using this example.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
  }

.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #212121;
    z-index: 2;
} 

h1 {
    margin: 50px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    float: left;
    font-family: cursive;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E55D87 0%, #5FC3E4  51%, #E55D87  100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.navbar {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    
}

li { 
    display:inline-block; 
    margin:0;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

li:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px solid aqua;  
    transform: scaleX(0);  
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

li:hover::after { 
    transform: scaleX(1); 
}

.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E55D87 0%, #5FC3E4  51%, #E55D87  100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-family: cursive;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-size: 200% auto;
}

.button:hover {
    background-position: right center;
}

.my-photo {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-left: 700px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

 .h2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background: #19CFB1;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #19CFB1 0%, #C978CF 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
}
  
#text {
    background: #1338CF;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #1338CF 0%, #CF70AF 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    line-height: 50px; 
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
}

.home-image {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;    
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -1; 
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    background-image: url("./img/foto-mustang-6-shelby-gt500_01.jpg")   
}

.home-image::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

blockquote {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 60px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
 
blockquote:before {
    content: "\201C";
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #CBDDE7;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 362px;
    top: 596px;
    z-index: -1;
}

blockquote p {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 130px;  
}

.about {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#about{
    width: 1300px;
    height: 687px;
    padding: 0 80px;
    margin: auto;
}

.title {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: cursive;
    z-index: -1;
}

.title::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 180px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #111;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.title::after {
    content: "who i am";
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: crimson;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: #fff;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.image {
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.column-right {
    width: 55%;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>CV</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#home" class="button">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" class="button">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio" class="button">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="button">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1>My CV</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="home" id="home">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="home-header home-header-small">
            <div class="home-image"></div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="content-center">
                <div class="profile-image">
                <img src="" class="my-photo"/>
                </div>
                <div class="h2">Lorem ipsum</div>
                <p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <blockquote>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <footer>— <cite>Lorem ipsum</cite></footer>
            </blockquote>  
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section class="about" id="about">      
            <h2 class="title">About me</h2>
            <div class="content">
                    <img src="" class="image"/>
                <div class="column-right">
                    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum</div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit minus impedit maxime, quae soluta quis cumque perferendis! Doloribus quaerat, placeat iste facere, aspernatur ex cum veritatis laudantium, officia, non porro exercitationem incidunt quis dolore? Officia ex accusamus expedita optio, voluptatem minus? In maiores omnis aperiam earum ab molestiae beatae laborum blanditiis incidunt, delectus dolor, id voluptates optio aspernatur aliquam saepe atque labore?</p>
                </div>
            </div>    
    </section>
```

Comment: Your snippets seems to be brocken. i cannot reproduce your problem. But maybe try giving your section home some padding or margin top, for instance `.home { padding-top: 200px; }` (use as padding maybe the height of the header element...

Comment: your 'about me' title seems ok, how if you share the problematic part?

Comment: @MrNoob, I didn't quite understand you. I wrote there in the question that in small form, it looks like mine, but when you expand it to the whole page, it looks more or less normal.

Answer (score 0):

Another options is to use

```css
.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

/* or, instead*/
.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
  }

.header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #212121;
    z-index: 2;
} 

h1 {
    margin: 50px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    float: left;
    font-family: cursive;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E55D87 0%, #5FC3E4  51%, #E55D87  100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.navbar {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    
}

li { 
    display:inline-block; 
    margin:0;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

li:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px solid aqua;  
    transform: scaleX(0);  
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

li:hover::after { 
    transform: scaleX(1); 
}

.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E55D87 0%, #5FC3E4  51%, #E55D87  100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-family: cursive;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-size: 200% auto;
}

.button:hover {
    background-position: right center;
}

.my-photo {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-left: 700px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

 .h2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background: #19CFB1;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #19CFB1 0%, #C978CF 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
}
  
#text {
    background: #1338CF;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #1338CF 0%, #CF70AF 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    line-height: 50px; 
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
}

.home-image {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;    
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -1; 
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    background-image: url("./img/foto-mustang-6-shelby-gt500_01.jpg")   
}

.home-image::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

blockquote {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 60px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
 
blockquote:before {
    content: "\201C";
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #CBDDE7;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 362px;
    top: 596px;
    z-index: -1;
}

blockquote p {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 130px;  
}

.about {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#about{
    width: 1300px;
    height: 687px;
    padding: 0 80px;
    margin: auto;
}

.title {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: cursive;
    z-index: -1;
}

.title::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 180px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #111;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.title::after {
    content: "who i am";
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: crimson;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: #fff;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.image {
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.column-right {
    width: 55%;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>CV</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#home" class="button">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" class="button">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio" class="button">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="button">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1>My CV</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="home" id="home">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="home-header home-header-small">
            <div class="home-image"></div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="content-center">
                <div class="profile-image">
                <img src="" class="my-photo"/>
                </div>
                <div class="h2">Lorem ipsum</div>
                <p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <blockquote>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <footer>— <cite>Lorem ipsum</cite></footer>
            </blockquote>  
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section class="about" id="about">      
            <h2 class="title">About me</h2>
            <div class="content">
                    <img src="" class="image"/>
                <div class="column-right">
                    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum</div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit minus impedit maxime, quae soluta quis cumque perferendis! Doloribus quaerat, placeat iste facere, aspernatur ex cum veritatis laudantium, officia, non porro exercitationem incidunt quis dolore? Officia ex accusamus expedita optio, voluptatem minus? In maiores omnis aperiam earum ab molestiae beatae laborum blanditiis incidunt, delectus dolor, id voluptates optio aspernatur aliquam saepe atque labore?</p>
                </div>
            </div>    
    </section>
```

Comment: Something has changed here in your answer, but in my project it was as it was and remained, what could be the reason?

Comment: I didn't understand. Is my answer working here and not in your project?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work in my project, I did as you suggested, but nothing changed.

Comment: Try to debug this by inspecting the `.header` element(s) for their affective css rules. You can also manually set style of element to add there.

Comment: Also, I wanted to ask, is it possible to somehow make the transition to the page smooth, by animation, for example, I am in Home, and when I click on About me, there is a smooth transition, is this possible with the help of CSS, without JS code?

Comment: I don't know about it. You can't probably but you can define `html {scroll-behavior: smooth; }` I never tried.